# Codemagic or Fastlane failing while exporting archive for iOS in Flutter projects

Tags: flutter, dart, continuous-integration, codemagic

**Problem**

For flutter projects when trying to do CI via Fastlane or Code magic getting an error.

**Error(s)**

> Unable to export archive: 2019-07-19 06:35:19.256
>   xcodebuild[3381:21183] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging
>   _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/r7/d9twdq011sb8d3q1p8f39cdr0000gn/T/Runner_2019-07-19_06-35-19.252.xcdistributionlogs'.
>   error: exportArchive: Symbols tool failed Error
>   Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Symbols tool failed"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Symbols tool failed} ** EXPORT FAILED
>   **

**Some Extra Detail(s)**

This issue is coming with recent master commits in Flutter git.

When using Flutter stable git branch we don't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Running `pod install` solved on my side. I'm using local Fastlane on flutter beta channel.